# Can’t do transaction from eos authority

Tags: transactions, authority

I created an eos account on eos authority and am trying to make a transaction, but it wants to confirm the account through anchor or cleos but I don’t have an account there and I can’t import the current one, how can I do it so that I can send tokens to other accounts, I only have public and private keys of this account